# How can you color each circle in the D3 circle pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, circle-pack

Here is an example of the pack layout in d3js:

http://bl.ocks.org/4063530

Is it possible to control the colors of the individual cirles?

Here is another example of the pack layout with colors:

http://bl.ocks.org/4063269

[image]

Can you help me understand how the colors are assigned to the bubbles in the second chart?

Comment: Did you actually try to modify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add the attribute `fill` to change the color:

```
node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d){ return d.color; });
```

In the example above, suppose your data contains a `color` field.

Comment: this is what worked for me:  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });  not sure if this is different from what you suggested, i.e., use of .style vs .attr

Comment: The fact is that `"fill"` is set in the css stylesheet, thus, it is a style, so you have to overwrite with the `style` command instead of `attr`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I believe you would have to firstly set color to the node first. My solution includes changes here: function recurse(name, node) {
  if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) {
    recurse(node.name, child);
  });
  else classes.push({
    packageName: name,
    className: node.name,
    value: node.size,
    color: node.color
  });
}
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788105/d3-circle-pack-setting-circle-colors/36407165#36407165